# Extra vertical space in the first row of a table

Tags: arrays

The code is shown below. When the first row does not contain a special cell (with two lines in a cell), this won't actually occur. But I'm not quite sure how to fix it.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{tabu} % tabular
\usepackage{multirow} % tables
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing % or \doublespacing
\newcommand{\specialcell}[2][c]{\begin{tabu}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabu}} % two lines in a table cell 
\tabulinesep=1.8mm % tabu vertical spacing/need {tabu} package

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \begin{tabu}{cccccc}
    \hline
    & \specialcell{aaa\\bbb} & \specialcell{aaa\\bbb} & \specialcell{aaa\\bbb} & \specialcell{aaa\\bbb} & \specialcell{aaa\\bbb}\\
    \hline
    a & a & a & a & a & a\\
    \hline 
    b & b & b & b & b & b\\ 
    \hline 
    c & c & c & c & c & c\\ 
    \hline 
    \end{tabu}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I just redefined `\specialcell` to use a stack, rather than a `tabu`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{tabu} % tabular
\usepackage{multirow} % tables
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing % or \doublespacing
%\newcommand{\specialcell}[2][c]{\begin{tabu}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabu}} % two lines in a table cell 
\tabulinesep=1.8mm % tabu vertical spacing/need {tabu} package
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\newcommand\specialcell[2][c]{\Centerstack[#1]{#2}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \begin{tabu}{cccccc}
    \hline
    & \specialcell{aaa\\bbb} & \specialcell{aaa\\bbb} & \specialcell{aaa\\bbb} & \specialcell{aaa\\bbb} & \specialcell{aaa\\bbb}\\
    \hline
    a & a & a & a & a & a\\
    \hline 
    b & b & b & b & b & b\\ 
    \hline 
    c & c & c & c & c & c\\ 
    \hline 
    \end{tabu}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The baselineskip of the stack can be changed with, for example, the declaration

```
\setstackgap{L}{22pt}
```

resulting in

[image]